# Ansible issue: using ansible to print all hosts in inventory as a list and reject the host IP on which playbook is running?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have an inventory file which I'm passing as a list and I have to print all IP addresses in  the inventory, except the current host on which the playbook is running on.

```
discovery_hosts: "{{ groups['all'] | map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_host']) | reject('search', ['ansible_hostname']) | join(',') }}"
```

`reject` is not working. I'm looking something like `grep -v` which can print everything except the IPaddress of the current machine in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than fixing your reject (which would probably work at the end), I propose to do the job before hand: remove the host from the `all` group before extracting data.  Here is the idea:

```
discovery_hosts: >-
  {{
    groups['all'] |
    difference([inventory_hostname]) |
    map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_host') |
    join(',')
  }}
```

Note that the name to remove is contained in `inventory_hostname` (as declared in your inventory). Be also aware that `ansible_host` will only exist if you declared it explicitly in your inventory.

Comment: How can i print current host name on which playbook is running? so that i can replace with [inventory_hostname]

Comment: `inventory_hostname` is the variable containing the current host on which the task is being run. You are defining `discovery_hosts` inside a task that runs on all your hosts right ?